# trouble in finding time complexiy of simple for loop statement

Tags: data-structures

i am new in coding and got problem in finding time complexity of simple `for` loop  consider

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
```

i have seen in some sites that the time complexity of above is 2n + 2
and as far what i understood

```
    1 for assignment i=0
    n+1 for comparision of i<n
```

but in case of i++
`n  times for i++` since the loop will iterate for n times given in some sites

```
so total time complexity `= 1+(n+1)*2 +n`
```

but i have problem as
i++ =i+1 (which is an arthemetic operation and assignment )
that is it require 2 operation that means n*2 total operation 
so total time complexity `=  1+(n+1)*2 +2n`

please help me to find out the correct result

Comment: It will depend on your compiler, etc. how exactly this is interpreted into machine code, and thus the *exact* complexity of it.  What's important is that it a *linear* function in n.  If you need something more exact, you need to make assumptions about the machine code that's being generated.

Comment: `i++ = i + 1` is incorrect operation due to `i++` returns `rvalue` but assignment operator requires variable to be `lvalue`

Comment: where can i find more detail can you give a link if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment can be done with one operation, e.g.: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arithmetic_instructions.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
```

If the loop body complexity is:

- `O(1)`: so loop complexity is `O(N)`
- `O(M)`: so loop complexity is `O(N * M)`
- `O(N)`: so loop complexity is `O(N ^ 2)`

and so on.

Comment: can you explain more about ++i terms in time complexity

Comment: @0x82 The complexity of `++i` os `O(1)` or constant complexity. It doesn't matter what value `i` has, every time incrementing will took the same time.

Comment: i am asking how it work as i++=i+1 that are 2 operation

Comment: First of all `i++ = i + 1` is invalid construction. Have you ever tried to compile it?? But if we pretend that we have some operation `X` which needs to perform 2 suboperations, it's still `O(1)` as long each of these two operations takes `O(1)` to complete.